# Round pandas data frame/series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a pandas data frame that looks like this (much longer but here's the top few rows):

```
>df_fill['col1']

0      5987.8866699999998672865
1     52215.5966699999989941716
2       201.8966700000000003001
3         3.8199999999999998401
```

I want to round the entire column to 5 decimal places. I can round it to integers, but not to any amount of digits after the decimal. The type for the column is float.

```
> np.around(df_fill['col1'], 0)

0      5988
1     52216
2       202
3         4

> np.around(df_fill['col1'], 5)

0      5987.8866699999998672865
1     52215.5966699999989941716
2       201.8966700000000003001
3         3.8199999999999998401

> (df_fill['col1']).round()

0      5988
1     52216
2       202
3         4

>(df_fill['col1']).round(5)

0      5987.8866699999998672865
1     52215.5966699999989941716
2       201.8966700000000003001
3         3.8199999999999998401

> (df_fill['col1']).round(decimals=5)

0      5987.8866699999998672865
1     52215.5966699999989941716
2       201.8966700000000003001
3         3.8199999999999998401

> str((df_fill['col1']).round(decimals=5))
'0      5987.8866699999998672865\n1     52215.5966699999989941716\n2       201.8966700000000003001\n3         3.8199999999999998401\
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: won't `df_fill['col1'].round(5)` just work?

Comment: What is `df_fill['col1'].dtype`?

Comment: @EdChum that did not work, trying that I still get the results with 19 digits after the decimal.

Comment: unutbu has a point, what is the dtype here?

Comment: @unutbu dtype('float64')

Comment: I can't reproduce this, you're going to have to post your numpy and pandas versions and some raw input data and code to reproduce your error

Comment: Can you show the output from `print(pd.get_option('display.display.float_format'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floats [can only represent a subset of the real numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error). It can only exactly represent those decimals which are sums of negative powers of two ("binary fractions").
After you round a float to 5 digits, the new float may not be the real number which has 5 decimal digits since the decimal part may not be exactly expressible as a binary fraction. Instead rounding returns *the float closest to that real number*.

If you have set

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.23g}'.format
```

then Pandas will show up to 23 digits in its string representation of floats:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.23g}'.format

df_fill = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[ 5987.8866699999998672865, 52215.5966699999989941716, 
                                201.8966700000000003001, 3.8199999999999998401]})

#                       col1
# 0 5987.8866699999998672865
# 1 52215.596669999998994172
# 2 201.89667000000000030013
# 3 3.8199999999999998401279

print(df_fill['col1'].round(5))
# 0   5987.8866699999998672865
# 1   52215.596669999998994172
# 2   201.89667000000000030013
# 3   3.8199999999999998401279
# Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

But if you set the float_format to *display* 5 decimal digits:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
```

then

```
print(df_fill['col1'].round(5))
```

yields

```
0    5987.88667
1   52215.59667
2     201.89667
3       3.82000
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Note the underlying float has not changed; only the manner in which it is displayed.

Comment: Yup, this was it. Still a little confused about it, but I confirmed by taking two rows that were equal up to the 5th place, and then unequal. Rounded them and while they still displayed the full digits, the rounded values were "equal". I changed the display to 5 only to ease my mind. Thank you!

Comment: note in 0.17.0, will have a ``DataFrame.round()`` method as well

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to a precision issue in representing floating point numbers. The number 5987.88667 cannot be represented exactly in a float, the nearest number that can be represented is 5987.8866699999998672865. Thus you already have the number closest to the number you want in the array, and rounding it to 5 decimal places will thus have no effect. You already have the correct invocation:

```
(df_fill['col1']).round(5)
```

You can see that it works if you try to round to 2 decimal places instead. So I suggest you don't worry about it. If the issue is how the number is displayed on the screen, then you can print the number to a string to the correct number of decimal places:

```
print "%.5f"%(df_fill['col1'])
```